# Cannot add XML fragment based on node attribute name

Tags: install4j

We have version 7.0.12. We're trying to add a new fragment to the following XML using the 'Insert XML fragment into XML Files' action:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ConnectorData>
    <Events>
        <Event id="ReportPrinting"></Event>
    </Events>
</ConnectorData>
```

we've used the following xPath Expression to locate the node with attribute id="ReportPrinting"

/ConnectorData/Events/Event[id='ReportPrinting']

unfortunately, this fails with the following log entry:

```
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.xml.InsertXmlFragmentAction [ID 59]: Execute action
       Property files: [EventComponents.xml]
       Property fragmentFile: null
       Property fragmentInsertMode: Insert as last child
       Property fragmentSource: Direct entry
       Property fragmentText: <EventComponent ProductID="SmartOrganizer" ComponentID="RoomClose">
    <ExecutionOrdering>1</ExecutionOrdering>
    <BreakExecution BreakOn="True">true</BreakExecution>
</EventComponent>
       Property xpathExpression: /ConnectorData/Events/Event[id='ReportPrinting']
       Property downloadExternalEntities: false
       Property rollbackSupported: true
       Property validating: false
       Backing up C:\Program Files (x86)\Test\EventComponents.xml
[ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.xml.InsertXmlFragmentAction [ID 59]: No nodes found for XPath /ConnectorData/Events/Event[id='ReportPrinting']
        Execute action not successful after 23 ms
```

Do you have any idea why this might fail?

Answer (score 0):

Attributes are referenced as `@id` in XPath expressions. So your XPath should be

```
/ConnectorData/Events/Event[@id='ReportPrinting']
```

Comment: Thanks Ingo! It might be worth checking the information window for the 'XPath expression' as the attribute example there doesn't contain the '@' symbol.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know, we will fix this for 8.0.8.